# with google map api, do I need to remove listeners before I delete an overlay

Tags: javascript, google-maps, events

When I remove an overlay to google map, do I need to clear all its listeners (for memory purpose).
for example

```
 var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle(options);
 rectangle.setMap(map);
 google.maps.events.addListener(rectangle,'click', mycallback);
 ......
 //delete
 //do I need to remove listener first?
 rectangle.setMap(null);
 rectangle=null;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033821/do-i-need-to-remove-event-listeners) post, yes. Some older browsers do not handle garbage collection and failure to remove event listeners could cause memory leaks. And, what's the worst that could happen if you removed the event listeners before deleting the object?