# Do I need to remove event listeners in 2016?

Tags: javascript, events, cross-browser, dom-events

This question [was asked and answered in 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6033821/938236). However, the web scene has taken a considerable change and now IE6 and IE7 are out, IE8-10 are barely out ([under 1% each](http://gs.statcounter.com/#desktop+mobile+tablet-browser_version_partially_combined-ww-monthly-201503-201604)) and only IE11 is still there.

So, in 2016, **do you need to manually remove event listeners to avoid memory leaks?** Consider **only IE11** for the answer please. I am asking because I [created a small library](http://umbrellajs.com/) as an alternative to jQuery and would love to know if I have to remove them manually first. Of course the question is when using vanilla javascript, not jQuery.

Comment: Hey @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩, as you can see there is a 5 year gap and that makes a world of a difference. In the linked question, the answer is **"yes"**, while when I asked this question in 2016 the answer was **"no"**. So it's definitely not a duplicate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No**

See these answers:

- [Do I need to remove event listeners?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37096563/1106901)
- [If a DOM Element is removed, are its listeners also removed from memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12528067/1106901)

Also:

- [This](http://javascript.info/tutorial/memory-leaks#ie-lt-8-dom-js-memory-leak) article claims the DOM + JS reference cycle memory leak was fixed in IE8.

---

**Edit**: The article linked above is gone. [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20161202203921/http://javascript.info/tutorial/memory-leaks#ie-lt-8-dom-js-memory-leak) is a wayback machine snapshot.