# JS: What function will make my code DRY?

Tags: javascript, function, dry

**My Program**
An Etch-A-Sketch that initially draws on the grid in black. The user clicks **Erase** to color over the black squares. The user can also click **Rainbow" to draw a random color on each square, i.e. square[0] can be blue, square[1] can be purple...etc, they're randomized on each *mouseover*.

**Problem**
You'll notice that the code for **eraseGrid()** and **drawRainbow()** are nearly identical. I had to do this or the program wouldn't work properly. This is the only way for **Rainbow** to draw different colors on each *mouseover*.

**Goal**
If you look at the function I commented out at the bottom, I tried coming up with something I could use for both **eraseGrid()** and **drawRainbow()**, but when testing the function out, it wasn't working as intended. Instead of drawing a random color on each *mouseover*, it would create a random color (let's say blue) and draw blue on the grids. If I toggled **Rainbow** back on, it would create another random color (green for example) and draw that on the grids.
I don't understand why the function I created doesn't work as intended, whereas the repeated code does.

---

```
/**************************** Input->Button DOM ****************************/

const newGrid = document.getElementById('new-grid');
newGrid.addEventListener('click', createGrid);

const erase = document.getElementById('erase');
erase.addEventListener('click', eraseGrid);

const rainbow = document.getElementById('rainbow');
rainbow.addEventListener('click', drawRainbow);

/*********************** Grid variable and creation ***********************/

const main = document.querySelector('main');
const div = main.getElementsByTagName('div');

drawGrid(16, ((600 / 16) - 2) + 'px');
pickColor('#333');

function createGrid() {

    // removes divs from largest to smallest
    for (let i = main.childNodes.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        main.removeChild(main.childNodes[i]);
    }

    let size;
    do {
        size = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number from 1 to 64", ""), 10);
    } while(Number.isNaN(size) || size > 64 || size < 1);

    const numPx = (600 / size) - 2;
    let px = numPx + 'px';

    drawGrid(size, px);
    pickColor('#333');
}


function pickColor(color) {
    for (let i = 0; i < main.childNodes.length; i++) {
        main.childNodes[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function change() {
            main.childNodes[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
        })
    }
}

// draw grid of div elements
function drawGrid(size, px) {
    for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            const div = document.createElement('div');
            main.appendChild(div);
            div.setAttribute('style', `width: ${px}; height: ${px}; 
                float: left; border: 1px solid #333;`);
        }
    }

    // clear floats
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('class', 'clear');
    main.appendChild(div);
}

function eraseGrid() {
    erase.classList.toggle('erase');
    if (erase.className === 'erase') {
        rainbow.classList.remove('rainbow');
        main.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
            pickColor('#f2f2f2');
        })
    }
    else {
        main.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
            pickColor('#333');
        })
    }
}

function randColor() {
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        arr.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255));
    }
    return arr;
}

function drawRainbow() {
    rainbow.classList.toggle('rainbow');
    if (rainbow.className === 'rainbow') {
        erase.classList.remove('erase');
        main.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
            pickColor('rgb(' + randColor() + ')');
        })
    }
    else {
        main.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
            pickColor('#333');
        })
    }
    // changeColor(rainbow, 'rainbow', erase, 'erase', 'rgb(' + randColor() + ')')
}

/*function changeColor(newClass, newClassStr, oldClass, oldClassStr, color) {
    newClass.classList.toggle(newClassStr);
    if (newClass.className === newClassStr) {
        oldClass.classList.remove(oldClassStr);
        main.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
            pickColor(color);
        })
    }
    else {
        main.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
            pickColor('#333');
        })
    }
}*/
```

Comment: changecolor fires pickcolor repeatedly, which causes new eventlisteners to be created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the commented out changeColor function, you should be able to refactor it like this, if you put rainbow and erase in a parent object so you can find them by name.

```
const objects = {erase, rainbox};

function changeColor(str1, str2) { 
    objects[str1].classList.toggle(str1);
    if (objects[str1].className === str1) {
        objecs[str2].classList.remove(str2);
        main.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
            pickColor('rgb(' + randColor() + ')');
        })
    }
    else {
        main.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
            pickColor('#333');
        })
    }
}
```

Again, as @me_ mentioned in a comment. Adding a eventListener on each click is very likely not what you want. After the fifth click you'll have five eventListeners, and five functions `function(){pickColor('rgb(' + randColor() + ')');}` that will be be called every time you mouse over "main" (ever expanding for each click...)

(Edit because the comments are so restrictive:)

> 00Saad: I saw there's a removeEventListener() method, would I implement it by adding main.removeEventListener('mouseover', function(){ pickColor('rgb(' + randColor() + ')'); }) after the addEventListener?

No, store the function away in a variable if you want to be able to easily remove it later.

`function(){...}` <-- This is the piece of code that creates the new function.
So this: `main.removeEventListener('mouseover', function(){...})`, would create a new anonymous function, and try to remove from main's event-listeners (where it doesn't exists).

Besides, if you use a stored function (`const a = function(){..}`) and later `addEventListener('mouseover', a)`) that will *kinda* solve the problem since you cannot bind the same function to the same event multiple times anyway (it will have no effect).

But then the following `addEventListener`-calls would make no difference so in your case it would make much more sense to put your mouseover-listener outside the scope of `changeColor()`.

```
let isRandomColor = true;
main.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
  pickColor( isRandomColor ? randomColor() : '#333' );
});

function changeColor(){
  if (...){
    isRandomColor = true;
  } else {
    isRandomColor = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why's it bad to have too many event listeners...does it cause memory issues?

Comment: When you add an eventListener you are saying: "Call this function every time I do a 'mouseover` on main".  It will keep working until you destroy it (or until you leave the page). So the next time you click the rainbow: "Call this function everytime I do 'mouseover' ".  It will create a **new** eventListener, and now, every time when you mouseover main, two functions will trigger. The old eventListener is still there.

Comment: This is what you are doing: https://codepen.io/kumorig/pen/QreNMo and also check this question out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033821/do-i-need-to-remove-event-listeners-before-removing-elements (good to know about event-listeners)

Comment: If it's intentional then it's not bad. But do you *really* want to call `pickColor` 43 times on mouseover? (sorry for the spam!)

Comment: I saw there's a removeEventListener() method, would I implement it by adding  
**main.removeEventListener('mouseover', function(){  
   pickColor('rgb(' + randColor() + ')');  
  })**

after the addEventListener?

Comment: Edited in an answer to that particular question!

Comment: I appreciate everyone's help with this. I didn't bother to remove the event-listener or use a stored function in this particular program, since it works, and I want to move forward (plus it's not something I'm doing professionally), but I'm going to keep this knowledge in mind for future programs.

Answer (score 0):

You can work out the names but it looks like you're just doing

```
function go(str1, str2){
    document.getElementById(str1).classList.toggle(str1);
    if (document.getElementById(str1).className === str1) {
        document.getElementById(str2).classList.remove(str2);
        main.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
            pickColor('#f2f2f2');
        })
    }
    else {
        main.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
            pickColor('#333');
        })
    }
}
```

Just call it with `go('erase', 'rainbow')` or `go('rainbow', 'erase')`

```
function eraseGrid(){
    go('erase', 'rainbow');
}

function drawRainbow(){
    go('rainbow', 'erase');
}
```

Comment: I copied it from his code. At the top of his code snippet you can see he gets erase and rainbow elements by their id.